# Parsing nested JSON in Elm

Tags: json, elm

I have this situation

```
-- this is in post.elm
type alias Model =
  { img : String
  , text : String
  , source : String
  , date : String
  , comments : Comments.Model
  }

-- this is in comments.elm
type alias Model =
  List Comment.Model

-- this is in comment.elm
type alias Model =
  { text : String
  , date : String
  }
```

I am trying to parse a JSON so formed

```
{
  "posts": [{
    "img": "img 1",
    "text": "text 1",
    "source": "source 1",
    "date": "date 1",
    "comments": [{
      "text": "comment text 1 1",
      "date": "comment date 1 1"
    }]
  }
}
```

This is my `Decoder`

```
decoder : Decoder Post.Model
decoder =
  Decode.object5
    Post.Model
    ("img" := Decode.string)
    ("text" := Decode.string)
    ("source" := Decode.string)
    ("date" := Decode.string)
    ("comments" := Decode.list Comments.Model)

decoderColl : Decoder Model
decoderColl =
  Decode.object1
    identity
    ("posts" := Decode.list decoder)
```

It does not work, I am getting

> `Comments` does not expose `Model`.

How do you expose a `type alias`?

How do I set up `Decoder` for my example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit: Updated to Elm 0.18**

To expose `Comments.Model`, make sure your Comments.elm file exposes all types and functions like this:

```elm
module Comments exposing (..)
```

Or, you can expose a subset of types and functions like this:

```elm
module Comments exposing (Model)
```

There are a few problems with your decoders. First off, to match your JSON, you're going to need a record type alias that exposes a single `posts` list Posts.

```elm
type alias PostListContainerModel =
  { posts : List Post.Model }
```

You are missing a decoder for comments. That will look like this:

```elm
commentDecoder : Decoder Comment.Model
commentDecoder =
  Decode.map2
    Comment.Model
    (Decode.field "text" Decode.string)
    (Decode.field "date" Decode.string)
```

I'm going to rename your `decoder` function to `postDecoder` to avoid ambiguity. Now you can fix the `comments` decoder line by using the new `commentDecoder`.

```elm
postDecoder : Decoder Post.Model
postDecoder =
  Decode.map5
    Post.Model
    (Decode.field "img" Decode.string)
    (Decode.field "text" Decode.string)
    (Decode.field "source" Decode.string)
    (Decode.field "date" Decode.string)
    (Decode.field "comments" (Decode.list commentDecoder))
```

Lastly, we can fix `decoderColl` by using that posts wrapper type (`PostListContainerModel`) we created earlier:

```elm
decoderColl : Decoder PostListContainerModel
decoderColl =
  Decode.map
    PostListContainerModel
    (Decode.field "posts" (Decode.list postDecoder))
```

Comment: Could you please have a look at this question? I'm stuck again with this, a little bit further on towards the result I hope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845299/structure-mismatch-while-parsing-json

Comment: Elm newcomers: careful, this answer contains pre-0.18 syntax. In particular, `:=` has become `field` and `objectX` has become `mapX`. See [Upgrading to 0.18 / Renamed functions in core](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.18.md#renamed-functions-in-core)

Comment: also `module Comments (Model) where` has become `module Comments exposing (Model)`

Comment: Thanks Ronan and farmio - I've updated the answer to Elm 0.18

Comment: Hm... Upper limit is `map8`. What if we got a json object with 50 fields?

Comment: @qed, take a look at [NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline/latest) for a clean way to decode values with more than 8 fields. There is also [`|:`](https://github.com/elm-community/json-extra/blob/2.0.0/docs/infixAndMap.md) from [elm-community/json-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/json-extra/2.6.0/Json-Decode-Extra) if you prefer the applicative style