# Structure mismatch while parsing JSON

Tags: json, elm

I am trying to parse a JSON file and show it to the user, here a simplified version

```
{
  "posts": [{ 
    // some properties 
    comments: {
      // some more properties
    }
}
```

This is my code, I know it's a lot I'm not really sure what to remove to isolate the problem, every time I try I get a different error that seems to lead me nowhere.

```
type Action
  = NoOp
  | GetPosts
  | ShowPosts (Maybe { posts : List Post.Model })


init =
  ( { posts = Nothing }, Effects.none )


update action model =
  case action of
    NoOp ->
      ( model, Effects.none )

    GetPosts ->
      ( { model | posts = Nothing }, getPosts )

    ShowPosts maybePosts ->
      ( { model | posts = maybePosts }, Effects.none )


view address model =
  div
    []
    [ button [ onClick address GetPosts ] [ text "Click to get posts!" ]
    , viewPosts model.posts
    ]


viewPosts maybePosts =
  case maybePosts of
    Nothing ->
      div [] [ text "No posts to display. Try clicking the button" ]

    Just posts ->
      ul [] (List.map Post.view posts)



-- This is the key to map the result of the HTTP GET to an Action
-- Note: Task.toMaybe swallows any HTTP or JSON decoding errors


getPosts : Effects Action
getPosts =
  Http.get decoderColl "./posts.json"
    |> Task.toMaybe
    |> Task.map ShowPosts
    |> Effects.task


type alias PostListContainerModel =
  { posts : List Post.Model }


postDecoder : Decoder Post.Model
postDecoder =
  Decode.object5
    Post.Model
    ("img" := Decode.string)
    ("text" := Decode.string)
    ("source" := Decode.string)
    ("date" := Decode.string)
    ("comments" := Decode.list commentDecoder)


commentDecoder : Decoder Comment.Model
commentDecoder =
  Decode.object2
    Comment.Model
    ("text" := Decode.string)
    ("date" := Decode.string)


decoderColl : Decoder PostListContainerModel
decoderColl =
  Decode.object1
    PostListContainerModel
    ("posts" := Decode.list postDecoder)
```

I am getting this error from the compiler

> Function `start` is expecting the argument to be:
>
> ```
> { ...
> , view :
>       Signal.Address Action
>       -> { posts : Maybe { posts : List Post.Model } }
>       -> Html
> }
> ```
>
> But it is:
>
> ```
> { ...
> , view :
>       Signal.Address Action -> { posts : Maybe (List Post.Model) } -> Html
> }
> ```

I can't understand where that extra `{ posts : Maybe` is coming from in the definition of `view`.

Previous question with some extra background: [Parsing nested JSON in Elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801776/parsing-nested-json-in-elm)

UPDATE:

Got an answer in the elm community google group, here's the gist https://gist.github.com/rundis/23d7ef6ea42842e6f527

Answer (score 1):

I think the definition of `ShowPosts` is getting in the way. You have this:

```elm
ShowPosts (Maybe { posts : List Post.Model })
```

But it should probably be this:

```elm
ShowPosts (Maybe (List Post.Model))
```

Making that change will cause you to have to update a few other places, but follow the compiler messages and it should lead you to the right place.

One of the places that will need updating is `getPosts`, where you'll need to take the list of posts out of that wrapper object. That should be as simple as this:

```elm
|> Task.map (ShowPosts << .posts)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks :) Yeah, that's one of the things I've tried but I got an error I didn't really understand. I'll try harder.

Comment: I tried changing this definition `type alias PostListContainerModel =
  List Post.Model` because it makes this way for me, but no, I get `Cannot find variable `PostListContainerModel` which puzzles me even more.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an example of eliminating the need to pass around `PostListContainerModel`. That is useful for decoding but really, you can avoid passing it around by using `List Post.Model` everywhere else by updating `getPosts`.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to understand where to go after that, I've changed `decoderColl =
  Decode.object1
    (List Post.Model)
    ("posts" := Decode.list postDecoder)` but that errors, I thought that was correct but I probably misunderstood the docs.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in that last comment - `PostListContainerModel` is still needed for json decoding in the example you posted, but you can just pass around a `List Post.Model` for all other functions rather than a record that looks like `PostListContainerModel`

Comment: Thanks for that, I changed it back. I'll work my way through the other errors.